# Access the BPM ID3 tag in iPhone OS 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mp3, id3

Is there any way to access the BPM (beats per minute) ID3 tag of a song on your iPod using the iPhone OS 3.0 SDK? I'm looking at

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

and i don't see it:

```
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID;      / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType;         / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyTitle;             / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle;        / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyPodcastTitle;      / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyArtist;            / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist;       / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyGenre;             / filterable */
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyComposer;          / filterable */
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics;
NSString const MPMediaItemPropertyIsCompilation;     / filterable */
```

Comment: For the record, MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute was added in iOS4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see it, submit a Radar to have it included, or perhaps to ask for an API with a more general means of querying tag values.